sql call count not working in the way I am expecting
im after done a mysqli call but for some reason something going wrong and a can't understant why:
($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('
    SELECT `t`.`id`,`t`.`created`,`t`.`cat`,`t`.`quest`,`t`.`answer`,
    COUNT(`l`.`id`) AS liked, SUM(CASE WHEN `l`.`user_id`=? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    COUNT(`v`.`id`) AS views, SUM(CASE WHEN `v`.`user_id`=? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM `training` `t`
    LEFT JOIN `likes` `l` ON (`l`.`mod`="training" AND `l`.`task_id`=`t`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN `views` `v` ON (`v`.`mod`="training" AND `v`.`task_id`=`t`.`id`)
    WHERE `t`.`id`= ? 
    GROUP BY `t`.`id`
    LIMIT 1') or trigger_error($mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR));
$stmt->bind_param('iii',$user['id'],$user['id'],$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $date, $cat, $quest, $answer, $saves, $saved, $views, $viewed);
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();

for some reason seems that $saves and $views add to each others, for example views to specific record has 2 and 4 likes (records)
what is coming out is: $saves=8 and $views=8
for 5 likes and 2 views, I'm getting $saves=10 and $views=10
maybe I have something wrong but I can not spot where
I have tried to go through but can't sort it myself
i need that views and likes will work properly

When you have multiple joins, you're counting the rows in the cross product, so you get duplication. See the linked question.

After adding distinct  seems to be sorted, thanks Barmar

That will fix the COUNT(id), but it won't help with SUM()

for sum i need 1 or 0, so looks like all is working fine now
